# Error con pyodbc.connect

Tags: python, odbc

Tengo unas bases de datos a las que me quiero conectar vía pyodbc, si introduzco el código:

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.dataSources()
```

Obtengo lo siguiente:

```
    Out[28]: 
{'dBASE Files': 'Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)',
 'Excel Files': 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)',
 'MS Access Database': 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)',
 'bdicent': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'troya': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'bdicred': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'bdisolicitud': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'bd_reportos': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'bd_prendarios': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'bd_credito2': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'bdigaran': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'dbterfin': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'bd_garantias_liq': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)',
 'Visio Database Samples': 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)',
 'bdsolicitud': 'IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)'}
```

Pero cuando intento conectarme a un DNS en particular se le genera un error que no he podido solucionar:

```
con=pyodbc.connect('DNS=bd_reportos')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-27f04177a1ab>", line 1, in <module>
    con=pyodbc.connect('DNS=bd_reportos')

InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especificó ningún controlador predeterminado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Alguien podría darme alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal?

- Ya intenté introducir el UID y PWD
- Ya cambie la versión de 64 a 32 bits

AYUDA!!!

Answer (score 0):

Saludos intenta realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLSRV01;DATABASE=DATABASE;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD')
cursor = conn.cursor()

#ahora un query basico
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mi_tabla ")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row
```

Para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar la documentación:

[Python SQL Driver - pyodbc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017)

[Connecting to SQL Server](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Esa URL de conexión sirve para informix? (Que así es como la reporta la consulta en la pregunta)

Answer (score 0):

Basado en la [repuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/252733/133488) de Diego Avila, puedes hacer esto

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLSRV01;DATABASE=DATABASE;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD')


# query

res = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM mi_tabla ", con=conn)
res
```